# How to remove hidden line breaks from TXT file in C?

Tags: c, mips, txt

I'm attempting to grab each line from a TXT file and then pass that line into variables, which I will match up in an if statement. My txt file is:

```
add $t0, $t1, $t2
addi $t0, $t1, 30352
```

It properly removes the commas and sends "add", "$t0", "$t1", "$t2" to their respective variables and then translates them to the binary representation using if statements. It works for every variable except for $t2 because there is some kind of hidden line break that I cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove. My if statement looks like

```
else if(strcmp("$t2", reg) == 0)
{
 return r10;
}
```

which should be returning 01010 but instead never evaluates true.

How can I cleanse this of the line break in C?

Update: Here's how I'm reading the file

```
FILE *fp;
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;

void sendLine()
{

//Open file, check it's not empty
fp = fopen("mymipsfile.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
        remove_all_chars(line, ',');
        interpertLine(line);
        decodeLine(0);
        printf("\n");
}

fclose(fp);
if (line)
{
    free(line);
}
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And here is how im splitting it into the variables

```
void interpertLine(char currentLine[])
{
   //Extract the first token
   char * token = strtok(currentLine, " ");
   op = token;
   //Loop through the string to extract all other tokens
   int i = 0;
   while( token != NULL ) {
      //printf( " %s\n", token ); //printing each token
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
      if(i == 0)
      {
          rs = token;
      }
      else if (i == 1)
      {
          rt = token;
      }
      else if (i == 2)
      {
          rd = token;
      }
      i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you read in the data? Maybe you can prevent character from being to your variable in the first place.

Comment: Look at your text file in a hex editor.  Maybe it has Windows CRLF line endings.  After you read a line of text, try trimming known line ending off the end of it.  Example: https://godbolt.org/z/rfWz744Ph

Comment: If you're using POSIX [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), then the newline is preserved.  You need to zap it.  Since you're told how many characters were read and the last one is almost always a newline, you could use `line[--read] = '\0';` to zap it.  You could also use `line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = '\0';` but that scans the entire line whereas the direct array access does not.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help I appreciate it

Comment: You could also use `const char delims[] = " \t\r\n";` and pass `delims` as the delimiter parameter to `strtok()` — or `strtok_r()` or `strtok_s()` if they are available — so that blanks, tabs, carriage returns and newlines are all just treated as delimiters and not included in the tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply limit the comparing length to visible characters only:

```
else if (strncmp("$t2", reg, sizeof("$t2") - 1) == 0)
{
  return r10;
}
```

Note1: I'm using 'sizeof() - 1' to prevent comparison the trailing null termination byte (0), existing on the end of each string literal "...."

Note2: My solution will generate 'false positives' if 'reg' points to any string beginning with "$t2", for example: "$t20", "$t2abc" etc.
So, the better way is replacing the first invisible character to 0, then compare full size like below:

```
char *tmp_reg = reg;
while (tmp_reg++)
{
  if (tmp_reg < ' ') // is invisible?
  {
    *tmp_reg = 0; // replace invisible to 0
    break; // we don't need to compare more
  }
}

// ....

else if (strcmp("$t2", reg)) == 0)
{
  return r10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was taking me forever

Comment: Using `strncmp("$t2", reg, sizeof("$t2") - 1)` means that both `$t2` and `$t23` (and …) will be matched as `$t2`, which is probably not a good idea.  It's commonly seen as an idiom, but it isn't reliable.  The fix is to simplify the test to `strncmp("$t2", reg, sizeof("$t2"))` (omitting the `-  1`).  This compares the null terminating byte on the fixed string with what might or might not be the null terminating byte on the variable string — so if the variable string is longer than the fixed string, the strings compare unequal.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - you are right, my solution compares only beginning part of string pointed by 'reg'.